# Matlab: descending binary to ascending binary like [0 0 1 0] to [0 1 0 0] or 1011 to 1101?

Tags: matlab, math, binary

I have arrays that stores only binary numbers like the below, binaries are of the size 1x31. Now I want to make the last bit the first and the first bit the last and so on. The choice of data structure is probably very poor here -- when I learn to play with binaries I probably get rid of the array. The binaries make the ordering of the arrays far easier with a simple sort. Anyway this is puzzle now:

**Is there some ready command in Matlab for changing desceding binary to asceding binary?**

**Input**

```
>> C(21,:)

ans =

   (1,11)       1
   (1,16)       1
   (1,17)       1


>> full(C(21,:))

ans =

  Columns 1 through 11

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1

  Columns 12 through 22

     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0     0

  Columns 23 through 31

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

**Goal for the output with some command such as invertDec2Asc**

```
>> invertDec2Asc(C(21,:))

ans =

   (1,21)       1
   (1,16)       1
   (1,15)       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `num2str` followed by `fliplr`

```
revnum = fliplr( num2str(num) )
```

**Test**

```
num = ['101010';'010101']
revnum = fliplr( num2str(num) )

num =

101010
010101

revnum =

010101
101010
```

Comment: @thewaywewalk That's true. Somehow didn't notice that binaries are string. I am used to `num2str` when dealing with numbers and it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

`flipud` or `fliplr` is what you're looking for.

[Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fliplr.html)

```
fliplr([1 0 1 0]) = [0 1 0 1]
fliplr('1010') = '0101'
```

format of binaries in matlab: '1010', e.g. created with `dec2bin(10)`

Comment: `flip(...)` and `fliplr(...)` work, what is their difference? +1

Comment: "ud" stands for up and down, and "lr" for left, right, so it primarily matters for a matrix. So you can specify in which direction you to flip it. There is also `flipdim`.

Comment: The `flip(...)` works with vertical and horizontal -- but they do not work with binaries like flip(11100001), hmmm...

Comment: you see there a various options for every type of vector/matrix

Comment: Where? I cannot see anything that could do 11001-->10011, I am able to do it with arrays but not with real binary numbers.

Comment: @hhh what I actually don't understand, why you said `fliplr` wouldn't work for e.g. `1010` - I haven't checked it, but it does. The conversion `num2str` is quite pointless.

Comment: >> fliplr(1010)

ans =

        1010

Comment: but a binary number is `'1010'` and not `1010`.

Comment: >> fliplr('1010')

ans =

0101 <--- ok now it works but did not know you meant it! Examples always help...